# Passing an ArrayList From Server to Client Java (Trouble)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serialization

it might be a silly question I don't know, but it seems that I am quite stuck here.

So I have a server where I have added a few elements in an array list like this

```
ArrayList<Accounts> acc= new ArrayList<>();
```

on `run()`

I have something like this

```
oos.writeObject(acc); 
oos.flush();
```

If I `System.out.println(acc);`   It shows everything just fine.

on client side I am just using something like this:

```
ArrayList<Accounts> obj;

obj = (ArrayList <Accounts> )ois.readObject();
```

but it doesn't read anything in the end.

This is the error from Server:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1857)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1766)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1273)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1411)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1557)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at MyThread.run(ServerTwoThread.java:52)
```

I think that server cant send the list for some reason, and yes my account class is Serializable!

Would love some input!

EDIT: I found it, it wasn't oos, but ooos ...

Comment: i had initialized `ObjectOutputStream` with a `DataOutputStream` object in my application

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code that i had used in my application

```
public void run() {
        try {
            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            names.add(din.readUTF());   // store the user name in arraylist
            Iterator iter = list.iterator();
        Socket socket;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            socket =  (Socket) iter.next(); // creating ArrayList to be written on the stream
            dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(dout);
            obj.writeObject(names); //write the list of users in stream of all clients
            dout.flush();
            obj.flush();
        }
        } catch (Exception oe) {
            System.out.println(oe);

        }
    }
```

i know its not the exact answer to yur question but it would help you somewhat

Comment: Can you provide more code so that we can help you further?

Comment: Hmmm I have tried a few things that work. For example on a simple server-client without threaded classes etc , I have tried it with: Client side: ArrayList<String> obj; obj = (ArrayList<String>)ois.readObject(); System.out.println(obj);  Server Side: ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); oos.writeObject(list); oos.flush(); And this is works just fine! But in the code I posted in my original it doesn't work. I really don't get it :(((

Comment: @YnsHnrksn you have provided only a small snippet of the code, so we can't comment much about it. If you can provide more code, help would be provided in a better way. And don't forget to upvote/accept answers if they help

Comment: alright i just found it  , sorry it was a typo on the stream I used, it ate 2h of my life -.- .